# knockout validation doesn't add hasError class if exclude validationElement binding

Tags: validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have added knockout validation to my model.

This works fine:

```
//init validation
ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    insertMessages: false,
    messagesOnModified: false,
    decorateElement: true,
    errorElementClass: 'hasError'
});

// has required validation for model observable
self.CompanyName= ko.observable(data ? ko.unwrap(data.CompanyName) : '').extend({ required: true });
```

**HTML**

```
//binding
<span class="inline-edit-view" data-bind="text: CompanyName, validationElement: CompanyName"></span>
```

This adds `hasError` to the invalid element. If I remove `validationElement`, though, it doesn't work.

**Question is**: Why should I use `validationElement`? It seems counter-intuitive to me. 
 I already have `extend {required: written}` for each element and I do not want to write a `validationElement` binding for each observable.

Comment: If you use the `value` binding instead of the `text` binding then you don't need to explicitly add the `validationElement`...

Comment: Where can I read about this? What is 'value' and what is 'text' binding difference in this case?

Comment: This is not really well documented: The ko.validation plugin amends the `value` binding so if you use the `value` binding you will get the element decoration for "free" ontherwise if you use other bindings like the `text` you have to the add `validationElement` binding manually.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `validationElement` binding because you are using the `text` binding.

The Knockout.Validation plugins overrides the `value` and the `checked` bindings to apply the different validation aspects like the `errorElementClass` so if you are using one of this two bindings then you don't need to explicitly use the `validationElement` binding.

However if you are using different bindings like `text` then you are responsible to mark your HTML with the `validationElement` and the `validationMessage` bindings if you want the validation plugin to use your classes or insert error messages etc.